# Circular dependency between resources AWS::S3/LAMBDA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Description:
When defining AWS::Serverless::Function as a trigger of AWS::S3::Bucket, currently it is impossible to SAM predefined policies with restricted access.

so for example let's take a look at the following template:

```
Resources:

  BlobsBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub "blobs-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}"


  ProcessBlobFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: blobsprjct/
      Handler: processBlob.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Policies:
        - S3ReadPolicy:
            BucketName: !Sub "blobs-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}"
        - AmazonRekognitionFullAccess
      Events:
        BlobsBucket:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: !Ref BlobsBucket
            Events: s3:ObjectCreated:*
```

This will fail with:

> Error: Failed to create changeset for the stack: blob, ex: Waiter
> ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure
> state: For expression "Status" we matched expected path: "FAILED"
> Status: FAILED. Reason: Circular dependency between resources:
> [ProcessBlobFunction, ProcessBlobFunctionBlobsBucketPermission,
> BlobsBucket]

All resources say to set BucketName - I've already had it, I also add permission (Not sure that its needed, cause Error stayed bigger for 1 point)

```
  AllowS3ToCallLambdaPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      FunctionName: !Ref ProcessBlobFunction
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !GetAtt BlobsBucket.Arn
```

And this will fail with:

> Error: Failed to create changeset for the stack: blob, ex: Waiter
> ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure
> state: For expression "Status" we matched expected path: "FAILED"
> Status: FAILED. Reason: Circular dependency between resources:
> [ProcessBlobFunction, ProcessBlobFunctionBlobsBucketPermission,
> AllowS3ToCallLambdaPermission, BlobsBucket]

I am stuck and cannot find a solution for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `!Ref BlobsBucket` in your function. Your bucket has **fixed and predefined** name. So use the name instead:

```
Bucket: !Sub "blobs-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}"
```

Similarly for the bucket ARN in permissions. In addition, you can add [DependsOn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) to force the correct order of resource creation.

Comment: Invalid Serverless Application Specification document. Number of errors found: 1. Resource with id [ProcessBlobFunction] is invalid. Event with id [BlobsBucket] is invalid. S3 events must reference an S3 bucket in the same template.

Comment: I'm stuck with a similar issue. Does anyone have solved it?

Answer (score 0):

A work around is to explicitly state the policy in the statement.

```
  Policies:
    - Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
            - s3:GetObject*
          Resource:
            - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${BUCKET_NAME}"
```